# How can I use a macro in padding a number in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to use a macro in sprintf statement. It is like this :

```
#define MACR 6

....
int Number= 5;
char Formatted[30];
sprintf( Formatted, "%06d", Number );
```

Here I would like to use MACR instead of 6. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `*` format specifier to pass the width as argument. Something like this should work:

```
sprintf( Formatted, "%0*d", MACR, Number );
```

But please use a constant not a MACRO.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is just to specify the length with
a `'*'`, and pass the macro as an argument:

```
sprintf( formatted, "%0*d", MACR, number );
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate strings, something like:

```
sprintf( formatted, "%0" STRINGIZE(MACR) "d", number );
```

using the usual STRINGIZE macro:

```
#define STRINGIZE_HELPER(x) # x
#define STIRNGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_HELPER(x)
```

(Of course, the easiest and safest solution is just to forget about `sprintf`, and use `std::ostringstream`.)

Comment: You lost the `0` that is part of the original format and didn't use the `.` that means the `0` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Have the complete format in the macro:

   ```
   #define MACR  "%06d"

   sprintf(Formatted, MACR, Number);
   ```
2. Use the `*` width specifier:

   ```
   #define MACR 6

   sprintf(Formatted, "%0*d", MACR, Number);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAKE_TEXT(x) #x
sprintf( Formatted, "%0"MAKE_TEXT(MACR)"d", Number );
```

Comment: What happens if I want to change this to something determined by the user at run-time?

Comment: While you can do that, the `*` notation is a better option.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII how can a macro be changed at runtime?

Comment: @neagoegab what I'm referring to is changing the padding based off of user input, or something that I may not want to be a macro.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes you can do that but the question is about using a MACRO.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, yes I understand... but then you will post a question describing that :)

Comment: This answer is valid given the question and does not deserve this -1, this is an alternate answer that shows how to use MACRO within text. It for sure won't win the best answer contest but i will come back and +1 tomoroow when i will have some points. This answer allows to see alternative.